# Mr. Zimmerman knows the answer. Do you?

Tags: story, knowledge

I met Mr. Zimmerman a few weeks ago. He came to me, took a piece of paper and wrote the following:

> How many roads must a man walk down
>   Before you call him a man?
>   How many seas must a white dove sail
>   Before she sleeps in the sand?
>   Yes, 'n' how many times must the cannon balls fly
>   Before they're forever banned?
>   The answer, my friend, is blowin' in th' wind.
>   The answer is blowin' in th' wind.

He would swear that there is only one answer to all those questions, but I don't know what it is. He did mention something about a new album and how, after that, Mr. Adams would agree with him (or maybe not), but that does not help me.

Can you find the answer to Mr. Zimmerman's questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to LeppyR64 we know Mr. Zimmermann is actually

> [Bob Dylan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dylan)

And he is singing his songtext of:

> [Blowin' in the wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowin%27_in_the_Wind). This song asks us how many times must we make war on one another before we learn that it's useless?

However, the first question: *"How many roads must a man walk down?"* is also known as:

> The Ultimate Question in the novel of Douglas Adams, who is mentioned in the text.

Of course, the answer for that is:

> [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)

Fun fact reference, the "new album", of Dylan

> is called Triplicate and is released March 2017. Fun fact: This album length is 95 minutes and **42** seconds.

Comment: But who is Zimmerman?  I know the answer, I want it in the answer :)

Comment: Took off the riddle tag. This is on the right track, just a few bits missing...

Comment: I understand it's all about the story, but I am not sure what hints Mr. Zimmerman is giving us. Perhaps I'm on the wrong track, searching for Dylan's albums.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dylan

Comment: Well done! Just follow LeppyR64's suggestions (regarding the name "Zimmerman") and I will accept your answer.

Comment: I hate Google. Searching for "Zimmermann" shows me news articles for the shooting in America or some weird Facebook results, not the real name of Mr. Dylan himself. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Well done, Mike!

Comment: Was a good, fun question! Took me some time, but eventually I got there, hehe.. :)